# GPS longitude and latitude through SMS listener

Tags: java, android

I developed an app where when Emulator A sends an sms to emulator B (with the app open), B sends the location coordinates back to A via SMS.The problem is that when i start the emulator the onlocationchanged get triggered and so the coordinates are returned succesfully. If i rerun the app on the same emulator, the locationchanged wont get triggered so the latitude and longtitude values remain null. How can i make sure that the onlocationchanged gets called everytime the app is started please ? Thanks

Comment: If the location doesn't change, why would that method run? You could store the location in SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

This is how I set up my LocationRequest until I get a GPS lock (a GPS signal of acceptable accuracy).  I receive coordinates every second, whether the user moves or not.  Once I get a lock, I slow down the request to every 10 seconds and change the minimum displacement to 10 meters.  Note, having the smallestDisplacement set at 0 allows the onLocationChanged method to trigger without any movement.

```
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);             //1 second
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);      //1 second
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0);    //always accept gps
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```